# Write a function that return a random letter from a string n number of times in a .txt file

Tags: python

This is for intro to CS at my school:

I need to write a function that takes 2 arguments: n and myString and will write a .txt file that returns a random letter from the string n times.

ex:

```
randomCharacters(5, "hello orange")
```

would write

```
h
o
g
e
r
```

so far I have:

```
import random
def randomCharacters(n, myString):
    myFileName = "nCharacters.txt"
    randomChar = open(myFileName, "w")
    for element in range(n):
        s = ""
        for _ in myString:
            randItem = random.choice(myString)
            s = s + randItem
        randomChar.write(s + "\n")
    randomChar.close()
```

it will write the file and will write n lines, but in the lines there is more than one random letter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the inner for loop, that loop will mean you have too many random characters on each line

Comment: @georgebills123: FYI, with just inner loop removed, there is no guarantee that duplicates are removed. You might get `h o o g r`, `h g o r o`, etc.

Comment: The question wasn't to do with duplicates, it was having more than one character per line

Comment: @Austin thank you but the parameters of the assignment did not say they had to be unique characters from the string